# how do I make an iOS-like slide switch using apache wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a wicket webapp and I would like to add a panel with some slide switches to control functionality, like this:

[image: iOS slide switch]

I can't find any examples of how this can be done in wicket - can anybody suggest anything?  NB I need to use ajax to send API calls to the server when the user changes the value of the switch.

I think I'm using wicket 1.4.22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any JS/CSS solution and just integrate it with Wicket to send the Ajax call when the value changes.
Here is one such JS solution: http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/